# How to add monetary symbol in tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add monetary symbol in the field amount, it should be like that: $ 8,90 but the symbol doesn't appear. Here is my code:

```
<page string="Ventes et entrées">
                    <field name="sale_cash_in_ids">
                        <tree>
                            <field name="date"/>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="partner_id"/>
                            <field name="currency_id" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>
                            <field name="amount" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                    <group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right">
                        <field name="sale_cash_in_sum"/>
                    </group>
                </page>
```

And the python code in pos_session.py:

```
class AccountBankStatement(models.Model):
_inherit = "pos.session"

sale_cash_in_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name="account.bank.statement.line", inverse_name="sale_cash_in_id",
                                   compute="_compute_cash")
cash_out_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name="account.bank.statement.line", inverse_name="cash_out_id",
                               compute="_compute_cash")
sale_cash_in_sum = fields.Monetary(string="Total", compute="_compute_total")
cash_out_sum = fields.Monetary(string="Total", compute="_compute_total")
sale_cash = fields.Monetary(string="Vente", compute="_compute_sum")
cash_in = fields.Monetary(string="Entrées", compute="_compute_cash_in")
cash_out = fields.Monetary(string="Dépenses", related="cash_out_sum")*
```

The python code in account_bank_statement.py

```
class AccountBankStatementLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.bank.statement.line'

sale_cash_in_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="pos.session")
cash_out_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="pos.session")
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add currency field in tree view or form view, first you will have to define currency and company field in the desired model and then assign default currency to the currency field. If currency field is empty then you will not be able to see currency symbol.

For example code should look like this:

```
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company', 
    default=lambda self.env.user.company_id.id, index=1)
currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency',
    default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.currency_id.id,
    required=True)
```

Why I define company field here because I want to assign default currency to currency field that is set on company.

Your xml code looks fine.

Hope this code helps you.

Comment: I forgot to say that I added those two fields (sale_cash_in_ids, ) in pos.session, and pos.session alread had currency_id any company_id. Let me edited the post.

Comment: Did you assign any currency to the currency field?

Comment: Yes, in the native tree that use account.bank.statement.line model, currency symbol appear correctly near the amount.

Comment: So you are adding the currency symbol in odoo default model or your custom model?

Comment: in my custom tree. In fact, it is not a custom model, but a native model _name = "account.bank.statement.line".

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your python code.

```
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company',default=lambda self.env.user.company_id.id, index=1)
currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency', default=lambda self:self.env.user.company_id.currency_id.id,required=True)
```